# How to normalize a database schema

Tags: database, database-design, normalization

I have two tables:

```
customer (
  client_id(PK), 
  lastname, 
  firstname, 
  flightID (Fk)
)

flight (
  flight_id(PK), 
  flightarrival, 
  flightdepart
)
```

My questions are:

- Are there any problems with the schema?
- How can I add data to the flight table?

I really want to separate the two because bulk tables are confusing.

Here is an example of a "bulk table":

```
customer(
  client_id(PK), 
  lastname, 
  firstname, 
  flightarrival, 
  flightdepart
)
```

but I want to normalize it and separate it from the customer table and just link them.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "bulk table"?

Comment: Tables with a lot of datas in it or unnormalized table?. Sorry, I just don't know what term I should use. XD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The schema you proposed would mean that each customer could be related to one (not zero, not more than one) flight, which feels wrong.

In essence, I think you have a many-to-many relationship, which you can do with three tables:

```
customer (id(PK), lastname, firstname)

flight (id(PK), flightarrival, flightdepart)

customer_flight (
    customer_id REFERENCES customer(id),
    flight_id REFERENCES flight(id)
)
```

Comment: For new records, INSERT into `customer` and `flight` first, then `customer_flight`. (In fact because of the FK relationships, you can't do it any other way...)

Comment: If you already have non-normalised data, you can migrate it to normalised by using `INSERT INTO ... SELECT DISTINCT ...`. to create the `customer` table and the `flight` table. Then you can use a final `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` to populate your customer_flights table by joining your existing non-normalised table with you two new `customer` and `flight` tables.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a separate cross-reference many-tomany - table which will be like

customer_flights(id int (pk),customer_id int, flight_id int,timecreated(optional))

one customer may have several flights booked like in past and in future...

and later join the two tables basing on the records in this table

Comment: sir, if that's the case how would my insert statement look like?

Comment: should I insert first in the customer table then into the flight table and then into the customer_flights?

Comment: Yes, Both customer table and Flight table should be filled first!!! Then you create a record in this many-to-many table which will reference these IDs from the two tables.

Comment: thank you very much mr. and all of those who helped me It is clearer for me now. Sir would you mind answering another question? something came up with my mind will reading your answers...

Comment: go ahead and ask. what is it?

Comment: I've posted it as another question sir. I just finished writing it.