# Find number in array via mysqli query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I am trying to get data out of the mysql database where for example number 1 is in an array (The array is json btw and it looks like:

```
["1","2","5","11","16","23","25"])
```

now lets say i want to get all rows where number 1 is in this array is that possible and if so how?

i have tried to use:

```
- WHERE category_ids IN (1) (not sure if i have used this right)<br>
- WHERE category_ids LIKE %".$catid."%<br>
- WHERE category_ids LIKE '%".$catid."%'<br>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: which version of mysql are you using?

Comment: In would be better and correct option

Comment: So, in your database, you have a field with a `string` like this `["1","2","5","11","16","23","25"]` and you want to filter the result where this column have a specific number? Is that the current scenario or did i misunderstood something?

Comment: @Michael i am using mysql 5.6 (also making use of mysqli)

Comment: @Clyff That is what i am trying to do yes, so its basically if this Array has 1 in it then get me this row otherwise skip it

Comment: @Timo Whats the dataType of that field?

Comment: @Clyff I use a varchar field

Comment: You really should should normalize your schema.

Answer (score 0):

you can do by this:

```
WHERE 1 IN (your_array_here)
```

after translate:

```
WHERE 1 IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

Comment: Where should i put the name of the row like mine is category_ids i assume you put  it on 1

Answer (score 0):

You can search like you do with strings, like this:

```
WHERE myColumn LIKE '%"1"%';
```

That was your third option in your question, what was wrong with it?

**EDIT:**

Full query: `select myColumn FROM table WHERE myColumn LIKE '%"1"%';`

Obs: as **@symcbean** pointed out, would be better (if possible) normalize your schema. I could not find good examples of tutorials in english, but you can take a look at [here](http://agiledata.org/essays/dataNormalization.html) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292257/how-to-normalize-a-database-schema)

Comment: The problem here is that the data in the column is not a string, or does not appear to be a string. It appears to be an array for which you would use `IN`

Comment: @JayBlanchard I see your point. I just working with the fact that is a `varchar` field filled with this text. So it's possible to make a search just like we do with a regular text

Comment: You can put almost anything in a `VARCHAR` field. I do not think the OP is sharing the actual data, so any answer would be a guess.

Comment: @Clyff woud it be recommended to switch it to another type or?

Comment: @JayBlanchard this ["1","2","5","11","16","23","25"] is what is actually in the field

Comment: and @Clyff for some reason it returns a NULL